BigQuery: Specifying non-hive partitioning
I have a Google Cloud Storage bucket that contains a Parquet data lake structured as below:
bucket/deviceid/message/yyyy/mm/dd/xyz.parquet

I aim to use BigQuery to create external tables to enable serverless SQL queries from this bucket (with the end goal of visualizing the data in Grafana dashboards). To do so I wish to leverage partitioning.
As evident, my data is not hive-partitioned. In my previous setup in Amazon Athena I managed to get around this via my AWS Glue Job, where I could define my partitioning logic as below:
# Define the partition keys and other table properties
    partition_keys = [{"Name": "date_created", "Type": "string"}]
    sample_file_key_parts = sample_file_key.split("/")
    s3_table_path = "/".join(sample_file_key_parts[:2])
    date_path = "${date_created}"
    full_s3_path = f"s3://{bucket_output}/{s3_table_path}/{date_path}/"

    projection_props = {
        "typeOfData": "file",
        "classification": "parquet",
        "partition_filtering.enabled": "true",
        "projection.enabled": "true",
        "projection.date_created.type": "date",
        "projection.date_created.format": "yyyy/MM/dd",
        "projection.date_created.range": "2019/01/01,NOW",
        "projection.date_created.interval": "1",
        "projection.date_created.interval.unit": "DAYS",
        "storage.location.template": full_s3_path,
    }


Is there an equivalent way to define custom partitioning in Google BigQuery? I'm OK with creating my external tables via a Python script as I will anyway need to do so at scale.
In the ideal scenario, I would be able to perform my partition pruning similarly to Amazon Athena, where I can add a filter as below:
WHERE date_created between '2020-04-22' and '2021-01-19'

I tried achieving something similar on-the-fly in my BigQuery SQL, but from what I can tell this does not effectively prune partitions and will therefore not be of practical use:
SELECT 
  DATE(PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_FILE_NAME, r'.*/(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})/.*'))) AS event_date,
  COUNT(AccelerationX) as cnt_accx
FROM 
  cssdataset2.tbl_0BFD7754_CAN9_ImuData 
WHERE 
  DATE(PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_FILE_NAME, r'.*/(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})/.*'))) BETWEEN '2023-06-22' AND '2023-06-22'
GROUP BY
  event_date


I assume you considered/tried it but I'll ask for clarity anyway- Is it not possible to rename the subdirectories in your bucket to make it hive partitioned? ie gsutil mv gs://mybucket/deviceid gs://mybucket/d_id=deviceid

Yes, that could be done, but the structure is created as part of a C based executable that is used across both Amazon, Azure, GCP and locally. I am trying to minimize 'differences' across these environments - and so far I have been able to use my existing structure with partitioning in all the others, except Google Cloud

Fair enough. As far as I know, hive partitioning is your only option for BQ/GCS. Sorry.

Thanks. Strangely, it seems like BigQuery only bills for the data that falls within my regular timestamp filter, i.e. when using something like t BETWEEN '2023-01-01 15:00:00' AND '2023-01-01 15:00:23'. Adding this on a 1 GB table query helps ensure only ~7 MB are scanned, for example - even though it does not seem to perform normal partition pruning. The query takes ~700 ms. If I then add the extra filter _FILE_NAME LIKE '%/2023/01/01%', the query takes ~400 ms, but scans the same amount. This seems strange, but makes it less critical with proper partitioning except for speed..
